# Is Inline Method Binding A Bad Practice?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, semantic-web, separation-of-concerns

I have been looking at Angular and it uses HTML attributes to bind events to models, like:

```
<form ng-submit="addTodo()">
```

Is this not considered a bad practice to do that? I know using inline JavaScript such as onclick is considered a very bad thing to do.

I am concerned about separation of concerns. Is this approach not going against that? Isn't it cleaner to use id or class attributes and bind events to DOM elements based on them in JavaScript? That seems less messy.

I am also concerned about ng attributes making HTML less semantic. HTML should stay as semantic as possible, with only presentation information.

I am currently investigating whether to use Angular for a web app I am working on and this is one of my concerns. I am more leaning towards using vanilla JS with something like RequireJS at the moment.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the fundamental nature of Angular, e.g., https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/kqZDVSUlkd0/sge6KsaaKQAJ. It's not "JavaScript + HTML" on the client, it's "Angular", a client-side MVC framework that happens to be specified via HTML and Angular attributes.

Comment: Take a look at silverlight ... If you want passive views i can understand but forget AngularJS this framework is view centric. Use Backbone with ModelBinder and i think you'll get that you want but with less API and still a lot of boilerplate

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. I am a little bit sceptical. You say it's not JavaScript + HTML but it still is for the browser. Browser still parses the HTML into a DOM and specifications and standards should be followed. I am going to investigate this issue more.

Comment: @ThomasPons I used SilverLight a bit in the past (well, it's dead now, just like Flash). It is not a good comparison with HTML as it uses XAML. I want views without event binding.

Comment: @RichardKnop What standard do you think *isn't* being followed? The standards allow inline JS, it's convention and practicality that pushed people away from it. If you're using Angular there's simply no point in decoupling the views from the events and data: that's what Angular *is*.

Answer (score 1):

#### Inline binding practice

New JavaScript frameworks seem to be revisiting bindings done in markup.  For a long time this was considered bad practice and it largely still is.  Opinions differ.  Proponents argue that binding in the markup in this way is more explicit.  You do not need to use additional classes that may change to create the bindings.

I would say that if you are going to use such inline bindings, they should be very simple.  That is, you should probably only be referring to a single method in the bindings rather than defining the method inline.

#### `ng` attributes

I believe Angular has the option to let you use `data-ng-*` instead which would make it valid / semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question!

It is actually the worst practice to bind events or behaviors in general in the dom.

¿But Why?

Let assume, and you know it is the most easy way and fastest to do that put a onclick on an element and define the function in a script tag but after a couple of elements/functions you have a lot of hard of maintain code. Thats why its a bad practice.

In angular all code is 'scoped' , wich means (allmost) an DOM scope and a JS scope where the code is valid/executed so you can reutilize directives/controllers (mainly) easily without having a lot of global functions binds.

About the points you expose

> I am concerned about separation of concerns. Is this approach not going against that? Isn't it cleaner to use id or class attributes and bind events to DOM elements based on them in JavaScript? That seems less messy.

Yeah if you think this way you are mixing the view with the controller, but in frameworks like backbone you define in controller your css selectors for behavior . 
Isn't the same mixing of patterns? - NO! angular way is better cause lets you make a lot of templates for the controllers reducing the js code to just data manipulation.

> I am also concerned about ng attributes making HTML less semantic. HTML should stay as semantic as possible, with only presentation information.

Semantic for whom, user or programmer ? i mean ui-behavior is part of view in a dom based software, so you can rewrite a template with no touching the controller. When you put ng-attibutes you are marking (htMl) for controller to react user events. You still semantic by descripting behavior in dom, I think, its better for your code.

> I am currently investigating whether to use Angular for a web app I am working on and this is one of my concerns. I am more leaning towards using vanilla JS with something like RequireJS at the moment.

AngularJS it is a new - way of organize your code, if you use vanillaJS youll find js pretty util to mantain your code, i promise you will save at least 80% of your css selectors and behavior descriptions.